# Cakephp3 Routes, no action name in url

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I wanted to ask, hou create route in Cakephp3, i want no action name in url.

now i have 
localhost/pages/contact and i want localhost/contact.

My link looks like:

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Kontakt'), ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'contakt']);
```

I have created route:

```
$routes->connect('/pages/:action/', ['controller' => 'Pages']);
```

This doesnt work, link have pages controller in content.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
$routes->connect('/contact', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'contact']);
```

And your view:

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Kontakt'), 'contact');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this code do the job:

```
$routes->connect('/contact', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'contact']);
```

But, what if i have 10 links, i must create 10 routes for 10 actions?

Comment: The answer is depend on your app. I you have just a single controller, or many controllers, etc.
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html